# How to show/hide a div on click of a button while that div should always visible on Desktop view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to show a div on desktop view but on mobile view i have to provide a button to hide/show that div.

Initially the div should be hidden on mobile view. i can use jquery,java script. There is a CSS class in which that div is hidden on mobile view and shown on desktop view using media-query.in mobile view i am doing `$('.classname').css('display','block/hide')` on click of the button.

The problem is when i click on the button to hide the div and switch to the desktop view the bar is also hidden on desktop view.

Comment: Please show whatever code you have done till now.

Comment: you need to do coding inside `$(window).resize(){..});`

Comment: if you run .hide() with jquery, then it will give the button display:none with inline styling, and your css in your stylesheet will be rendered powerless to it - either trigger the same thing on resize, or find another method - or just give it display:block !important; on desktop

Comment: Look into adding/removing a class when clicking that button. Then you can just use css specificity and media queries.

Comment: Hello Devendra, i have posted answer, hope you like it.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted an answer to your query please check you need to add jquery and run that small piece of script code. I have linked a working demo [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anmolsandal/psr1ukap/3/)

code

```
<div class="client">
 <h3 id="user">user</h3>
 <ul id="toggle-div">
   <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
#toggle-div {
 display:none;
}
```

Scripts

```
$("#user").click(function()
{
   $("#toggle-div").slideToggle(),
   $("#toggle-div a").on("click",function()
   {
       $("#toggle-div").slideUp()
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hidden class from bootstrap it's very usefull, you can simply hide a div section for certain devices 
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

Answer (score -1):

Nobody will use your website on mobile view and at some time switch to the desktop view. So don't worry!

If you want you can write a function that re-shows the hidded div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 767 ){ // your resolution
            $('#hiddedDiv').show();
     }  
    });
});
```

Comment: samuel what happen if on my desktop itself i go for mobile view through browser? So i am unable to understand what kind of answer it is.

Comment: This in reality never happens. Why should a user interact with your page with a mobile resolution on desktop? 

If you don't trust me you can write a function that re-shows the hidded div on resize at desktop resolution.

Comment: I am telling in the sense for testing purpose

Comment: I wrote you the function above